# Problems with python scapy portscanner

Tags: python, scapy

I programmed a port scanner to learn more about networking
but for some reason it only returns `port n is closed` for every port scanned.

```
import sys 
from scapy.all import *

 target = str(sys.argv[1])
 beg = int(sys.argv[2])
 ran = int(sys.argv[3])
 ptable = []
 print "beginning port scan on target: " + target
 for x in range(beg,ran):
    pkt = IP(dst=target)/TCP(dport=x,flags="S")
    ans,uans = sr(pkt,timeout=0.5)
    if TCP in ans:      
            if ans[TCP].flags == "SA":
                ptable.append(1)

            else:
                ptable.append(0)


print "======================== port scan summary ==========================="
print " "

for i in range(beg,ran):

    if ptable[i-1] == 1:

        print "port " + str(i) + " is open"
    else:
        print "port " + str(i) + " is closed"
```

Comment: Add `print`s in first `for` loop to see what result you get for `ans[TCP].flags`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `ans[TCP].flags` returns the numerical value (rather than a string that would moreover be ambiguous):

```
>>> TCP(flags='SA').flags == 'SA'
False
>>> TCP(flags='SA').flags
18
```

You should use `if ans[TCP].flags == 18:` instead of `== "SA"`, or better yet, `if ans[TCP].flags & 18 == 18:`.